# Move Identity Tables To Custom Schema Asp.Net Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-5.0

I Try To move all my identity Tables to Schema "User" using the following code in my context. it works fine for all except "AspNetUserClaims", "AspNetRoleClaims". What Should I do?

```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);

           builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles", schema: "User");
           builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>().ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims", schema: "User");
           builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers", schema: "User");
           builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims", schema: "User");
           builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins", schema: "User");
           builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles", schema: "User");
           builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserTokens", schema: "User");

       }
```

Migration Relating to lines above :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace MG.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class Mig2 : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                newName: "AspNetUserTokens",
                newSchema: "User");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                newName: "AspNetUsers",
                newSchema: "User");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                newName: "AspNetUserRoles",
                newSchema: "User");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                newName: "AspNetUserLogins",
                newSchema: "User");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles",
                newName: "AspNetRoles",
                newSchema: "User");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                schema: "User",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                schema: "User",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                schema: "User");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                schema: "User");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                schema: "User",
                newName: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                schema: "User",
                newName: "AspNetUsers");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                schema: "User",
                newName: "AspNetUserRoles");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                schema: "User",
                newName: "AspNetUserLogins");

            migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles",
                schema: "User",
                newName: "AspNetRoles");
        }
    }
}
```

When ``` base.OnModelCreating(builder); is at the top , moves all except "AspNetUserClaims", "AspNetRoleClaims" . when its at the end it viseversa.

Comment: Your code does not seem to have a problem. Can you share the migration that was created?

Comment: What if you set "User" as the default schema?

Answer (score 0):

`"AspNetUserClaims"`, `"AspNetRoleClaims"` check id types you have now in db.
You have problems because thay not the same. In base it should be like:

```cs
builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("AspNetRoleClaims", schema: "User");
```

```cs
builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims", schema: "User");
```

If you not set them customly...